# C# WPF UI freeze while datatable binding with Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

hi I am using DataTable for binding data with Listbox
DataTable row count = 1000+ and I have to load all row.

and when I binding

```
// Inside BackgroundThread
DataTable table = GetDataFromServer(); // Get Data (DataTable row count = 1000+)
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
      FilteredList.DataContext = table ; // UI Hangs Progress bar freeze around 20-30+ seconds

}), DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

XML Code

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="gridFilteredList" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <ListView Style="{DynamicResource MyListView}" Grid.Row="0" AllowDrop="True" x:Name="FilteredList"  
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"
              BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Black"  ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="syncList_ScrollChanged"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource BorderedListViewItemStyle}" SelectedItem="{x:Null}"
              Background="{DynamicResource DefaultMSBackgroundColor}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" Focusable="True" SelectionChanged="syncList_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single" MouseMove="syncList_MouseMove"
                  MouseEnter="syncList_MouseEnter"
             MouseLeave="syncList_MouseLeave">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid x:Name="FileItemGrid" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Cursor="Hand">
                            <Grid Margin="0 10 10 10" Height="35" >
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Grid.Column="0" Cursor="Hand"  Source="{Binding Path=imagestring, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource Image32StyleNearestNeighbor}" />
                                <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition />
                                        <RowDefinition />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" >
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Cursor="Hand" Foreground="#FF333333" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=name, Mode=OneTime}" />
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Cursor="Hand" Foreground="#FF333333" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=size, Mode=OneTime}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                    </Grid>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"  FontSize="11"  TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                                    <Run Text="{Binding Path=formattedtime, Mode=OneTime}" Foreground="#FFB3B3B3"/>
                                    <Run Text="-"/>
                                    <Run Text="{Binding Path=activity, Mode=OneTime}" Foreground="{Binding Path=StatusLabelColour, Mode=OneTime}"/>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="5 0 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                    <Grid Visibility="{Binding Path=DeleteImageVisible, Mode=OneWay}" ToolTip="Click to recover file" Name="SyncDelete" 
                                           Cursor="Hand" MouseLeftButtonDown="SyncDelete_MouseLeftButtonDown" Style="{DynamicResource GridWithBackground}">
                                        <Image x:Name="imgDelete" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/UserControl/SyncSummary_Delete.png" 
                                                Style="{StaticResource Image16StyleHighQuality}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Image Name="errorImage" VerticalAlignment="Center" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource Image16StyleHighQuality}" 
                                           Source="{Binding Path=errorStringImage, Mode=OneWay}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=errorStringToolTip, Mode=OneWay}" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="50000" UseLayoutRounding="True" />
                                </Grid>
                                <Button Grid.Column="1" x:Name="btnShare" Content="Share" Click="btnShare_Click" Margin="0,0,10,0" >
                                    <Button.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
                                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,0,10,0" />
                                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DefaultMSForegroundColor}" />
                                            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                                </Trigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}},Path=IsMouseOver, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                               Value="True" />
                                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=ShareBtnVisible, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                               Value="Visible" />
                                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Button.Style>
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>

                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
```

Should i use ObservationCollection or Any other design pattern for solve freeze issue ?

Comment: Make sure that the ListBox is virtualized. You should provide a reproducible sample: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Don't forget to include your XAML markup.

Comment: Is that many rows at a time really useful to your users?

Comment: ya its requirement..

Comment: @mm8 added xaml file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` attached property of the `ListView` to `false` which effectively disables the built-in UI virtualization and this affects the performance negatively.

Don't set this property to `false` if you care about rendering and scrolling performance.

Comment: ya its working good thanks @mm8....  just for my knowledge which binding is better for performance.. direct binding that i already user or binding using ObservationCollection

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "direct" binding but there is no noticable difference in performance between binding to an ObservableCollection<T> and binding to any other type of collection like for example a List<T>. But please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Comment: i have performance issues related to binding..so i just need what is the best way of binding ..

Answer (score 2):

Put your code in a `Task` (own thread) and your UI won't freeze anymore. You'll always have this problem when calling long running operations in the UI thread.

Comment: The long running GetDataFromServer method *is* called on a background thread...it is the rendering of the UI that is slow. And you can't render the UI on a background thread.

Comment: should i move this code "List.DataContext = table " into the Task ?

Comment: i used Task for but UI steal freezing ..possible to share example i am using Task.Factory.StartNew(() => method

Comment: You need to post your full XAML markup including any parent elements of the ListView.